# How do I prevent reimport when switching between computers using Unity3D Portable?

Tags: unity

I use Unity Portable on a passport drive where my projects are also stored.  How can I prevent Unity Portable reimport all assets from a project stored on the same passport drive when I change the PC I'm running both on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your external drive acquires the same drive letter & path every time before launching Unity.

Comment: Yes,  works fine,  sometimes you miss the obvious! Many thanks!